# ListView muito lenta na barra de rolagem

Tags: java, android, listview

Estou com um problema que não sei como solucionar, tenho um `ListView` personalizada com imagens e a barra de rolagem fica travando, mesmo com a lista carregada. Fica lento a lista para rolar.

Adapter:

```java
public class AdapterSegmento extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<Categoria> itens;

public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<Categoria> itens) {
    //Itens que preencheram o listview
    this.itens = itens;
    //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

/**
 * Retorna a quantidade de itens
 *
 * @return
 */
public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
}

/**
 * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public Categoria getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
}

/**
 * Sem implementaÃ§Ã£o
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Pega o item de acordo com a posÃ§Ã£o.
    Categoria item = itens.get(position);
    //infla o layout para podermos preencher os dados
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

    //atravez do layout pego pelo LayoutInflater, pegamos cada id relacionado
    //ao item e definimos as informaÃ§Ãµes.
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getTexto());
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());
  //  ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo)).setText(item.getSubtitulo());

    return view;
}
```

Classe que preenche a lista:

```java
private void gerarLista() {

    itens = new ArrayList<Categoria>();

    String[] categorias = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categorias);
    String[] drawableCategorias = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.categorias_drawable);

    listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

    // Vai recuperar os dois array's la do strings.xml e iterar sobre eles e criar os itens
    for (int i = 0; i < categorias.length; ++i) {
        itens.add(new Categoria(categorias[i], getResources()
                .getIdentifier(drawableCategorias[i], "drawable",
                        this.getPackageName())));
    }

    // Criamos uma lista que preenchera o ListView
    /*
     * itens = new ArrayList<Categoria>(); Categoria item1 = new
     * Categoria("Alimentação", R.drawable.alimentacao); Categoria item2 =
     * new Categoria("Esporte", R.drawable.esporte);
     * 
     * itens.add(item1); itens.add(item2);
     */
    // Cria o adapter
    adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, itens);

    // Define o Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
    // Cor quando a lista é selecionada para ralagem.
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Como resolver isso?

Comment: O que há nas classes `Segmento` e `Categoria`?

Comment: olá, eu alterei o post pois o adapter estava errado, nao existe a classe Segmento, apenas categoria.Bom, Categoria é apenas uma classe onde contem Titulo, e Imagem, e os get e set, é apenas uma forma de modelo.

Comment: Depois de rolares a lista toda as imagens continuam carregadas e a rolagem fica melhor?

Comment: não, sempre fica lenta mesmo as imagens carregadas.

Comment: Provavelmente é o decode da imagem. Já tentou colocar a linha  `((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());` dentro de um `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 4):

O problema está na arquitetura do seu algoritmo. A cada iteração no método `getView()` do *Adapter* você está inflando a *view* que deseja. Isso é uma má prática!

Você precisa utilizar o padrão de projetos *Holder*, que irá guardar as referências estaticamente das suas *Views* e irá melhorar a performance. Além disso, se você perceber, o método `getView()` recebe como parâmetro uma *View* (*view*) que nada mais é do que a *View* que você retorna neste próprio método, ou seja, eles utilizam a metodologia da recursividade.

Um exemplo bem básico do padrão Holder seria:

```
public static class ViewHolder {
  TextView hTextViewName;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  if (view == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_to_inflate, parent, false);
    holder.hTextViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
    view.setTag(holder);
  } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
  }

  String name = getItem(position);
  holder.hTextViewName.setText(name);

  return view;
}
```

Perceba a diferença!
Dessa forma você terá muito mais performance.

Resumindo, a partir do caso acima você apenas precisa adapta-lo ao seu contexto! :-)

Comment: Você pode olhar mais curiosidades sobre performance em ListView no próprio site do Android: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: mas isso seria no adapter? voce pode me mostrar como aplicar ao meu modelo? pois não to conseguindo. obrigada

Comment: Clara, é no seu adapter sim! Note que eu estou utilizando o mesmo método que você "getView()". Você só precisa adicionar o ImageView no meu ViewHolder e instanciar a variável das Views no ViewHolder. Não tem segredo, é só analisar o código e entender!

Comment: Clara, você conseguiu fazer com que o seu Adapter ficasse performático? Olha esse vídeo que fiz a muito tempo atrás http://debugcodigos.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/adapter-eficiente-android.html